# html class not updating (without page refresh)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am wanting an HTML class to update (without page refresh), the actual value is updating, and so are other items on the page correctly, but I cannot get the background colour of the class to update with the code I'm using.

I'm trying to get this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="info-box">
    <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="alert_icon"></i></span>
        <div class="info-box-content">
            <span class="info-box-text">Current Alarm State</span>
            <span class="info-box-number alerted"><small></small></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to change to this (from bg-green to bg-red):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="info-box">
    <span class="info-box-icon bg-red"><i class="alert_icon"></i></span>
        <div class="info-box-content">
            <span class="info-box-text">Current Alarm State</span>
            <span class="info-box-number alerted"><small></small></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="info-box">
    <span class="alert_colour"><i class="alert_icon"></i></span>
        <div class="info-box-content">
            <span class="info-box-text">Current Alarm State</span>
            <span class="info-box-number alerted"><small></small></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript is this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "update_all.php",
type: "post",
dataType: "json",
success: function(response) {                
    var len = response.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var alert_colour = response[i].alert_colour;
    $(".alert_colour").attr('class', alert_colour);  
    console.log(alert_colour);

    }
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
});

}, 1000);
```

Where the value of alert_colour when the page loads is `info-box-icon bg-green`.

When the page loads, it works correctly and shows the green box, but if the value of `alert_colour` changes to `info-box-icon bg-red` it does not update unless I refresh the page.

In the console log output I see it updating correctly (from `info-box-icon bg-green` to `info-box-icon bg-red` when the value changes, but on screen it just stays as it was when the page loaded. There are also other values on the page (text) that are updating, just the class element that doesn't.

Comment: When using attr, you are overwriting the class each time. According to your code, **alert_colour** isn't even in the HTML either.

Comment: Don't update the HTML attribute. Just add the new class to the element's `classList`. `document.querySelector(".alert_colour").classList.add(alert_colour);`

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the code I shared and it should be alert_colour not alert_status I have corrected it now. Will check on the comments and answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to change the class of **alert_status** to **alert_colour** or something random like that, you lose your reference point for changing future classes.

For my answer, I actually reference the alert_icon's parent as that will allow you to reference it no matter the classes.

Then as a test, I use addClass to add **info-box-icon bg-red**. Then I use removeClass with no arguments and chain that with addClass to add **info-box-icon bg-green**.

Also, since you are getting your classes from an array, just join the array with a space and you can pass them to jQuery's addClass function.

Using attr, just overwrites it everytime.

```js
let green = ["info-box-icon","bg-green"];
let red = ["info-box-icon","bg-red"];
$alertBox = $(".alert_icon").parent();

$alertBox.addClass(red.join(" "));
$alertBox.removeClass().addClass(green.join(" "));
```

```css
.bg-red{background:red;}
.bg-green{background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="info-box">
    <span class=""><i class="alert_icon">alert</i></span>
    <div class="info-box-content">
      <span class="info-box-text">Current Alarm State</span>
      <span class="info-box-number alerted"><small></small></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks. Apologies you are right, in the example I wrote aleet_status and it should be alert_colour. I'll check your answer later, thank you.